# CSS Safari : target table tr (even &odd) ignoring td and th to add background linear-gradient

Tags: css, html-table, tr, alternate

I want to define a new style of wordpress administration for the PostList page.
I don't know if CSS 3 has a property to allow background-image using linear gradient to display at the whole of css "table row" and not independently in each TR.
Until now all my attempts have been failures.
Perhaps the CSS4 will allow that ?

I can't find a simple css solution to target only tr from table ignoring all child (td and th) to use background-image:linear-gradient().

this solution :

```
table-name tr:nth-child(even)
```

add background to all td and th.

I want just target each row (tr) depending even or odd for me it would be direct childs from table.

I try

```
table-name:nth-child(odd or even)
```

or

```
table-name > *:nth-child(odd or even)
```

they don't work

Is javascript the only solution?
it's really strange that the W3C hasn't thought of this

Comment: Can you add a code snippet to your question to give a demo of what exactly you mean?

Comment: `odd or even` means all the elements

Comment: If you want to select all the `tr` elements why not just `table-name tr` as a selector?

Comment: thanks for your answers, I want a background for the whole row of tr and not separately for each td inside. in fact after anlayse the problem is only visible on safari and my solution works for all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a table with the `tr` elements set to have a linear gradient background.  Is this what you mean?

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr {
  background:linear-gradient(217deg, rgba(255,0,0,.8), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%),
             linear-gradient(127deg, rgba(0,255,0,.8), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%),
             linear-gradient(336deg, rgba(0,0,255,.8), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%);
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #333; 
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1:1</td><td>1:2</td><td>1:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2:1</td><td>2:2</td><td>2:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3:1</td><td>3:2</td><td>3:3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4:1</td><td>4:2</td><td>4:3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I say in the title , I want a background for the whole row of tr and not separately for each td inside. I founded a solution.

Comment: my demo does that, that's why I put the gradients at an angle so you can see that. Notice how each row goes from green to red and has a slight purple/blue on the bottom right corner of each row? If it's the lines you don't like, that's just a border that can be removed

Comment: thank you for clarifying this point, in fact after anlayse the problem is only visible on safari and my solution works for all.

Comment: Yeah i see your screenshot, that is really strange!

Comment: Yes it's so strange that my solution doesn't work in wordpress admin post list page . This issue is known apparently, but no solution works

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it doesn't work for safari wordpress post list page however Chrome, edge, firefox work fine. I still haven't found a solution for safari

```
table tr:nth-child(odd or even)::before
```

I put the problem and the solution below in the code snippet
Thanks for your answer.

```css
table,
.tb2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.tb2 {
  border-top: 5px solid;
  position: relative;
}
tr {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
table:not(.tb2) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(173, 173, 173), rgb(77, 77, 77)),
    linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 0%,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 0%,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 0%,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 100%
    ) !important;
  background-blend-mode: overlay, overlay, overlay, normal;
}
.tb2 tr:nth-child(odd)::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(173, 173, 173), rgb(77, 77, 77)),
    linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 0%,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 0%,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 0%,
      rgb(71, 29, 127) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 52%,
      rgb(99, 59, 126) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 54%,
      rgb(126, 89, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 56%,
      rgb(154, 118, 125) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 64%,
      rgb(181, 148, 124) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 82%,
      rgb(209, 178, 123) 100%
    ) !important;
  background-blend-mode: overlay, overlay, overlay, normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="tb2">
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

How safari render table tr with linear background :
[image]
[image]